# AWS EC2 403 Forbidden error

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, http-status-code-403

I have a `development` version of my application deployed on ec2 and I'm getting a `403 Forbidden Error` on navigating to the given public `IPV4` address.

I can start `rails c` after `ssh-ing` into the instance and manipulate the data from there.

Since the `403 Forbidden` is from `nginx` so I checked the error logs and found the following:

`*191 directory index of "/home/ubuntu/<app-name>/client/" is forbidden, client: <client-ip>, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "<host-ip>"`

Which is clearly the error I'm getting. Checking my `psql` logs shows me the following:

[image]

So the error is in how my `credentials` are setup.

I tried to go to my `pg_hba.conf` and my navigation route was `cd /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main` but I can't cd in to `main` after that since it says `permission denied`

I tried to view the `pg_hba.conf` by running:

`sudo vim /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf` but it tries to create a new file so clearly the file doesn't exist in that path.

I already ensured that my credentials are correct by doing `sudo -u postgres psql`

Also, the request from my front end is being made from `port 80` and I checked that I have that in the security configuration for my `EC2 server`

Comment: Did you try "sudo su" and then edit pg_hba.conf file?

Comment: @INVOKECloud I can't find the `pg_hba.conf` because when I tried the `sudo vim` it tried to create a new file in that path